# Set property of previous element in html (css)

Tags: html, css

I have `label` and email `input` like this:

```css
#emaillabel {
  color: red;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#email:focus~#emaillabel {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<label id="emaillabel">Email</label>
<input id="email" type="email" required placeholder="Email">
```

The problem is that label is shown in expected behaviour only when i put it html code after input.

In other words when i click on input i want see label that are before input.

I can use only css

Comment: can you explain clearly??

Comment: When i click on input i want see label that are before input

Comment: use hover effect

Comment: Read what i wrote carefully

Comment: yeah i have your code seems wrong let me check

Comment: your output stays same even after clicking on the input field. Please elaborate more clearly what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to show label when focus on input field

Comment: CSS can't select previous elements (just like there is no _apply to parent_ selector

Comment: Also note that `input type="email"` exists.

Comment: @connexo Thanks. But main problem is solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your current HTML structure, what you want to do CSS-wise is not possible, because you can only select *forward*.

That is, CSS has no *previousSibling* or *parent/ancestor* selector.

As a sidenote, your label is missing the `for`-attribute which works as the connector between the two.

What you can do is wrap both in a `div` (if it isn't already wrapped in another element, in that case just use that element) and use `:focus-within` pseudo class on the parent. [Browser support for `:focus-within`](https://www.caniuse.com/css-focus-within) is very broad, with IE being the usual exception. To make sure only browsers that support `:focus-within` hide the label, wrap the CSS declarations in a

```
@supports selector(:focus-within)
```

block:

```css
.input-label-group label {
  color: red;
}

@supports selector(:focus-within) {
  .input-label-group label {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  .input-label-group:focus-within label {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="input-label-group">
  <label id="emaillabel" for="email">Email</label>
  <input id="email" type="text" required placeholder="Email">
</div>
```

To make things a little more intuitive, you could - instead of switching visibility - also apply fadein/out using `opacity` and `transition`:

```css
.input-label-group label {
  color: red;
}

@supports selector(:focus-within) {
  .input-label-group label {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  }

  .input-label-group:focus-within label {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="input-label-group">
  <label id="emaillabel" for="email">Email</label>
  <input id="email" type="text" required placeholder="Email">
</div>
```

Comment: Why does it works only when i select elements by combining selectors? I mean I can`t specify id

Comment: The reason is that `id` selectors have a very high specificity, which makes it very hard to overwrite stuff. That is why the general recommendation is to not use `id` selectors in CSS. Introduction to CSS specificity: https://dev.to/ibn_abubakre/css-specificity-explained-1134